# I need to get last three month name in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to print previous  three month name with  this function

```
SELECT MonthName(CURRENT_DATE()) as month
```

With this query, I am getting the following :

```
month
September
```

I need to show like this it is possible

```
month
September
August
July
June
```

Comment: why u want to do it from mysql?

Comment: I am using mysql..

Comment: I can think of no sensible reason why you'd want to do this in SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DATE_SUB to subtract date with the help of interval

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) as first, MONTHNAME(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)) as second, MONTHNAME(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) as third
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATE_ADD` function with `MONTH` interval -1 thrice to get previous 3 months name. And then use `UNION ALL`.

**Query**

```
select MonthName(CURRENT_DATE()) as month
union all
select MonthName(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH))
union all
select MonthName(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -2 MONTH))
union all
select MonthName(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -3 MONTH));
```